# ABBYY Flexicapture Layout/Setup stations recognizing different things

Tags: ocr, abbyy

When I build an ABBYY flexicapture layout in layout studio it captures everything perfectly. After saving and exporting the layout into Setup station some of the information is missing,  particularly info in a repeating group.

For example, In a repeating group in Layout studio I can find all two 'Taxes' listed on the page. All are recognized at good quality with no errors. however, in setup station, only 1 of the 2 taxes will be captured.

FL studio Location_Taxes repeating block
[image: FL studio Location_Taxes repeating block]

FL Studio Captured Taxes (2/2)
[image: FL Studio Captured Taxes (2/2)]

Close up of Tax Repeating Group
[image: CLose up of Tax Repeating Group]

FC Studio Captured tax (1/2)
[image: FC Studio Captured tax (1/2)]

**Is there something I am missing that would cause the recognition to work in layout studio but not in Setup/Capture?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may have stumbled upon the problem (even though it should not be the problem). I was using a Regex to find the correct format for the Tax amount as shown in the image below.

[image: Regex for TaxAmount]

This was working in layout studio. However, in FlexiCapture the tax was not found. Upon removing the regex restriction and letting it just find anything Flexicapture would then work. You would think that this means that the capture studio was finding something that does not match the regex. But no, It found '.22' just like it should have.

Still wondering why it does this. I would like to continue to use regex's as it helps not recognize the wrong thing. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see your ABBYY FlexiLayout project as there could be a couple of causes, and I could test and confirm the solution.  But I think I see the issue clearly enough.

When you capture elements using a repeatable group element, make sure to expose those capture results in FlexiLayout Studio under Blocks into a block that has "has repeating instances" enabled (checkmark).  This will show all instances in FlexiCapture, not just the first captured instance.  I think this is your issue, because you stated that you see only one instance in FC.

There is a small chance that what you see in FlexiLayout does not match result in FlexiCapture even though everything is setup correctly.  But that is rare and happens only on particularly complex documents or some specific setup.  Example of this might be seeing 5 instances in FL and getting only 4 instances in FC.

Ilya Evdokimov

Comment: The Block is set to a repeating instance. I have added some pictures to help clarify what I am asking. Let me know if it helps. Thanks for looking into this!

Comment: In your second screenshot please expand the repeating group 'cu_Location_Taxes' so I could see elements inside.

Comment: I have added a close up picture of the repeating group 'cu_Location_Taxes'. This uses a keyword, 'Tax' and looks to the right of the keyword to find a decimal number (Taxes1). there is sometimes a '-' the the right of the decimal number  which we find with 'kwCredit'.